# Control number of display buttons through binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I wasn't sure the best way to word the title and couldn't find a related question, but if there is one then kindly direct me to it.

I'm trying to create a tender screen where the number of buttons displayed will be determined by how many types of tenders the user has setup (Cash, Check, Credit, Debit, Gift Card, etc).

So if I had a class like this:

```
public class TenderType
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    // ... other implementation details
}
```

And on my DataContext I have a TenderTypes collection declared like so:

```
public ObservableCollection<TenderType> TenderTypes { get; private set; }
```

Then how might I go about making my view udpate the number of buttons shown depending on how many TenderType instances are in the collection, and bind their Text properties to the DisplayName of the appropriate item in the collection?

Comment: Where are the buttons located, ListBox, stackPanel, Grid?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 For now a StackPanel, but I could definitely change it if another control would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ItemsControl and create a datatemplate for your TenderType to display a Button.

This way it will only show the buttons in your list

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="105" Width="156" Name="UI">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TenderType}">
            <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TenderTypes}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<TenderType> _sourceData = new ObservableCollection<TenderType>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TenderTypes.Add(new TenderType { DisplayName = "Stack" });
        TenderTypes.Add(new TenderType { DisplayName = "Overflow" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TenderType> TenderTypes 
    {
        get { return _sourceData; }
        set { _sourceData = value; }
    }
}

public class TenderType
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]